# how to split one column into two and group by id

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, sum

Can you help me with [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AnxDJ.png)?

I want to split the amount column into two column as debit and credit, and sum of debit and credit group by account id

This is my Table:

```
ID | GeneralLedgerHeaderId | AccountId | DrCr | Ammount
1  |           1           |     2     |   1  | 200.000
2  |           1           |     4     |   1  | 200.000
3  |           1           |     5     |   2  | 428.000
4  |           1           |     8     |   1  | 28.000
5  |           2           |     5     |   1  | 428.000
```

Comment: use case when base on condition

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Could you please [edit] your question and add a bit more information. Could you provide us with an expected output. Please also let us know what query you've tried already yourself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you want something as follows ?
You can use SUM() function with Partition By clause so you can get aggregations like [Count()](http://www.kodyaz.com/t-sql/sql-count-function-with-partition-by-clause.aspx) in a way of custom categorization defined in Partition By clause

```
select
    Id,
    GeneralLedgerHeaderId,
    AccountId,
    case when DrCr = 1 then Amount end as Debit,
    case when DrCr = 2 then Amount end as Credit,
    Summed = SUM(case when DrCr = 1 then (-1 * Amount) else Amount end) over (partition by AccountId)
from Transactions
```

Second query after comments are edit to this post

```
SELECT
    GL.AccountId,
    CA.Code,
    CA.AccountName, 
    SUM(CASE GL.DrCr WHEN 1 THEN Amount END) AS sum_debit, 
    SUM(CASE GL.DrCr WHEN 2 THEN Amount END) AS sum_credit,
    SUM(CASE GL.DrCr WHEN 1 THEN Amount ELSE (-1 * Amount) END) AS sum_total
FROM GeneralLedgerLine GL 
Join COA_Client CC 
    on GL.AccountId = CC.AccountId 
join ChartOfAccount CA 
    on CC.COA_Id = CA.COA_Id 
GROUP BY
    GL.AccountId, CA.Code, CA.AccountName
```

Comment: thanx its worked , but now i want to join two other table on account id , here is the query,

Comment: SELECT   GL.AccountId,CA.Code,CA.AccountName,
         SUM(CASE GL.DrCr WHEN 1 THEN Amount END) AS sum_debit,
         SUM(CASE GL.DrCr WHEN 2 THEN Amount END) AS sum_credit
FROM     GeneralLedgerLine GL Join COA_Client CC on GL.AccountId = CC.AccountId join ChartOfAccount CA on CC.COA_Id = CA.COA_Id
GROUP BY GL.AccountId

Comment: but it showing error,

Comment: Column 'ChartOfAccount.Code' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: Please change Group By clause as " GROUP BY GL.AccountId, CA.Code, CA.AccountName "

Comment: thanks, now i want to group by the accountid and Summed=debit - credit

Comment: Hello Ahmad, I added a second query to the original post. You will see a third SUM() with CASE statemen. You will see I multiply debits with -1 and sum them with credits. This logic is same in the first query too

Answer (score 5):

Assuming that `DrCr=1` means debit and `DrCr=2` means credit, you could use a couple of `case` expressions:

```
SELECT   AccountId,
         SUM(CASE DrCr WHEN 1 THEN Amount END) AS sum_debit,
         SUM(CASE DrCr WHEN 2 THEN Amount END) AS sum_credit
FROM     mytable
GROUP BY AccountId
```

Comment: thanx it's worked , now if i want to join the other table on account id how it's possible?

Comment: here is the query that i written.

Comment: SELECT   GL.AccountId,CA.Code,CA.AccountName,
         SUM(CASE GL.DrCr WHEN 1 THEN Amount END) AS sum_debit,
         SUM(CASE GL.DrCr WHEN 2 THEN Amount END) AS sum_credit
FROM     GeneralLedgerLine GL Join COA_Client CC on GL.AccountId = CC.AccountId join ChartOfAccount CA on CC.COA_Id = CA.COA_Id
GROUP BY GL.AccountId

Answer (score -1):

use case when with aggregation ,here i assume DrCr=1 debit and 2 means credit

```
select accountid, sum(case when DrCr=1 then Amount end) as dr,
sum( case when DrCr=2 then Amount end) as cr from your_table
group by accountid
```